# Comparing the result of a long-running task to the previous result

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a web service that returns a complex data structure representing the results of an intensive process. To make the service responsive, the process is run in an asynchronous Task.

The first time the service is called, an empty data structure is returned and the Task started.  Subsequent service calls return the cached data until the Task completes.  When finished, I need to determine if the results actually changed.  If so, I update a property that indicates the date/time the results were updated and reset the cached data so the new structure is returned by the service.  At some point in the future, based on a variety of reasons, the Task is restarted and the logic repeats.

I am looking for the most efficient way of determining whether the results have changed from the 'cached' data.  The simplest would be to implement Equals on every object in the structure with parent's equality based on their children's equality, etc. so calling Equals on the root objects would yield the desired result, but this requires crawling the entire structure and I'm not sure this is the best approach.

I also thought about starting with a copy of the original and using 'IsDirty' flags to indicate that a object in the structure has changed but worry that the copy operation could negate any performce benefits.

What approach would you use (and why)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a static method that recursively walks over all properties of 2 instances ( left and right ), which optionally can be controlled by using attributes, and calls the equals method of left over right. When one of the properties indicate inequality, we know that the 2 instances are different. This allows me to implement a minimum amount of code for comparison yet be fully in control in what gets compared and how it gets compared (by marking certain properties with a new attribute like [NoCompare] and by implementing custom equality logic).

Comment: Why would this be better than having the classes themselves implement Equals and performing a simple A == B check?

Comment: @SonOfPirate - That will work on a simple class where you only have to check a few fields and which is only used according to your exclusive description. By default, equality however is something much more complex. Try new object() == new object() and you'll find that it yields false because the address space is different (even though the data is exactly the same). Building a method that compares the primitives recursively of a class doesn't 'violate' default behavior and is easier to control.

Comment: Actually, Equals is designed to be overriden in code to provide Identity Equality, so you are correct that Equals wouldn't be the best method to use. (Equals is used by Hashtable, for instance, to determine if two items are equivalent. Using the base implementation, it is checking if the references are to the same object which is rarely desired behavior. MS added ReferenceEquals a while back to differentiate.)  That said, I'd think having the 'equivalence' criteria encapsulated within each object is better OO whether I call it IsSameAs or something else.

Comment: In other words, I wouldn't want to have the comparison logic in an external class but can see the idea of an external component that crawls the object graph (following the Visitor pattern) to determine overall equality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've provided the equals operator for your data object, you should be able to just check check that they're equal.

eg:

```
class CacheEntry<TCacheItem> 
{
   TCacheItem item; 
   DateTime? lastUpated; 
} 

class MyItem
{
   int Id; 
   string Foo; 

   public bool Equals(MyItem b) 
   {  
      return this.Id == b.Id && this.Foo == b.Foo;  // or something like this...
   } 
}
```

Then when you've got your result back:

```
   CacheEntry<MyItem> cacheEntry = ...; 
   MyItem newItem = ...; 

   if (cacheEntry.Item != newItem)
   { 
      cacheEntry.item = newItem; 
      cacheEntry.lastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow; 
   }
```

nb: Thread-safety checking left out.

Comment: Yea, this seems like the simple approach but requires time to crawl through the entire object graph to compare every object.

Comment: I'm not worried about thread-safety because neither object will be changed when I get to this point.

Comment: Following up on @Polity's post above, would you suggest a Visitor to handle crawling the object graph or have equality of an object's children part of it's own equality check?

Comment: For your objects, is the time taken to compare the objects really that large? Given you're comparing the output of a long-running task, and you should only need to do it a single time when the task returns.

Comment: Yea, I'm sold on using an equality check (not Equals, but a similar method that performs a Value Equality check). My only question is whether I should have the equality of all child objects factor into the equality of the parent.  In other words, do I have a Visitor that crawls the object graph or have the graph self-aware?